# Added a new NIC, can't reach any devices off the interface (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, nic

I was wondering if anyone could help me narrow this problem

I have a gateway running *Ubuntu server 10.04 (LTS)* and I have added a new NIC to it which is a *Intel PRO 1000PT GbE*, bringing the interfaces to 3.  The server sees the NIC, I can bring it up and assign it an IP but I can not reach anything devices off that interface.§

```
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr de:ad:de:ed:ab:ab  
          inet addr:10.10.1.1  Bcast:10.10.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 056a::eeff:fafe:feee:65de/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2445 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:256154 (256.1 KB)  TX bytes:154118 (154.1 KB)
          Memory:efdc0000-efde0000
```

(the traffic seen here is from ping test from other subnets.

from dmesg

```
[1234567.123036] e1000e: eth2 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[1234567.123042] 0000:02:00.0: eth2: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[1234567.124020] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth2: link becomes ready
```

the entry for eth2 in /etc/network/interfaces is

```
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address 10.10.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.10.1.0
    broadcast 10.10.1.255
```

If I try and ping the device off eth2 (a linksys wrt54gl) from the gateway it straight away gives a destination unreachable and *arp -a* does not return anything off the interface.

Similarly if I try and ping the interface of eth2 from a device on the network I can not and nothing showing up in *arp -a*

I can how ever ping eth2 (10.10.1.1) from any device off eth1

One other thing I notice in the output of *ifconfig -a* is that the last line of eth0 and eth1 differs from eth2  in that the former are *interupt* with the latter is *memory*

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:aa:bb  
          inet addr:99.99.99.99  Bcast:99,99,99,127  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: eee0::bbb:21ff:fe3a:535b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:119305917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:99141449 errors:1095 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:1035730 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2191962177 (2.1 GB)  TX bytes:3430112856 (3.4 GB)
          Interrupt:16 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:aa:ee:ee:dd:cc  
          inet addr:10.20.1.1  Bcast:10.20.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:aaaa:fe01:aaaa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:126352198 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:159212343 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3755860824 (3.7 GB)  TX bytes:501190807 (501.1 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr de:ad:de:ed:ab:ab  
          inet addr:10.10.1.1  Bcast:10.10.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 056a::eeff:fafe:feee:65de/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2445 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:256154 (256.1 KB)  TX bytes:154118 (154.1 KB)
          Memory:efdc0000-efde0000
```

eth2 has been tested with multiple cat5 which has been tested working.

**note I have sanitized some of the output**

Comment: The absence of `RUNNING` flag for `eth2` is a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you see anything on that interface by

   tcpdump -i eth2 -n
2. I have no idea why this should be the case but is perhaps something wrong with the routing?

   ip route show table all

   ip rule list